# Equalizing image in Codeigniter php using Imagick

Tags: php, codeigniter, imagemagick, imagick

I was trying to equalize image in Codeigniter PHP using Imagick, but the code is not working neither it is giving any error.  Anyone guide me how to make this equalize work?
I have edited the code, kindly help how to remove error?

Controller Code:

```
public function equalize_image(){            
   public function equalize($imagePath) {
            $this->image = new Imagick();
            $this->image->$imagePath;               
            //$imagick = new \Imagick(realpath($imagePath));
            $image->equalizeImage(); // line 378
            header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
            header("Content-Type: image/png");
            echo $image->getImageBlob();
        }
        public function equalize_image(){ 
            $data['title'] ='equalize';
        $config['upload_path'] = './assets/images/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        if(!$this->upload->do_upload()){
            $errors = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $post_image = 'noimage.jpg';
        } else {

                $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                $rangeinput = $this->input->post('rangeinput');                 
                if (exif_imagetype($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']) == IMAGETYPE_PNG){
                $realImages = imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']);
                $data['img2']=$config['upload_path'].'/'.$_FILES['userfile']['name'];
              //  imagefilter($realImages, IMG_FILTER_CONTRAST, $rangeinput);       

                $this->equalize($realImages);
                imagepng($realImages, $data['img2']);
                print $this->load->view('pages/result',$data,true);


        }     }
```

}

In view HTML code only image is displaying using Ajax, I don't know why equalizing not working.

Severity: error --> Exception: Call to a member function equalizeImage() on null C:\xampp\htdocs\ImageTools\application\controllers\Pages.php 378

Comment: how do you know that it is not working?

Comment: Because it is not echoing the image!

Comment: @ArSeN do you have any solution?

Comment: Have you installed ImageMagick along with Imagick. Imagick need to use ImageMagick.

Comment: enable error reporting and make sure imagick is installed on server

Comment: When I run the image equalize code in simple php, It worked fine and echoed the image but it is not working in codeigniter

Comment: there could be a variety of factors. if something is going wrong 100% and error should occur. please enable error reporting and check your logs. if that doesn't work reduce your code to narrow the problem down into manageable, testable, sections. also you have this line `$image->equalizeImage($imagePath);` and `$image` doesn't refer to anything. it is also used in the following line.

Comment: @Alex how can I reduce the code?

Comment: @Alex I have edited my question with error kindly guide how to reduce?

Comment: Well... You've provided 1 parameter when it expected 0

Comment: read code again I have edited?

Comment: weird. try commenting out everything after `echo $image->getImageBlob();`. also just noticed `$filedata1` is never defined.... i'm really really surprised you haven't been getting all these errors in some notification

Comment: Same result after commenting!

Comment: Sorry I just can't replicate the issue in my environment. Perhaps try a different image if you haven't already.

Comment: Means there is no mistake in the code?

Comment: @Alex reply kindly?

Comment: none that i see. as long as u've addressed `$filedata1=$this->upload->data();
    $data1['img1'] = base_url().'/assets/images/'.$filedata1['file_name'];` as it is useless until the `do_upload()` function is called.

Comment: Then please help me to overcome this problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176528/discussion-between-alex-and-mareena).